# If std::optional's bool conversion operator is explicit, why can we use an optional as a condition for an if statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement, type-conversion, c++17, option-type

Probably this means that I have misunderstood the meaning of `explicit` in general, but with specific example below, what allows a [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to be used as a conditon of an `if`, if [its conversion operator to `bool` is explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool)?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    std::optional<int> x;
    if (x)
        std::cout << x.value();
    else
        std::cout << "nothing";
}
```

Comment: `if (x)` is one of the contexts that counts as explicit conversion to bool. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions

Comment: Oh, ok, so it's what's named _contextual conversion_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). It looks to me that it says that the condition of an `if` is implicitly converted to `bool` if it can be explicitly converted to `bool`. Am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Yes you're misunderstanding it